# Openlayers - Route (linestring) behind of polygon after click

Tags: hide, openlayers, polygon, routes

I have a LineString and some points on it as Polygon. When I click on the yellow line, than the green polygon gets rendered behind the line. I would like to disable the click on the line.

Here is a picture about my problem
http://i57.tinypic.com/2rc3kg3.png

Here is a code snipet:

```
function PointDrawing(Lon, Lat, VectorLayer)
{
    var circlreFeatureStyle = new OpenLayers.Style();
    circlreFeatureStyle.fillColor = '#009900';
    circlreFeatureStyle.fillOpacity =0.8
    circlreFeatureStyle.strokeColor = '#004F00';

    var circle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
              new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(Lon, Lat),
              (1 * 15),
              30
          );
    circleFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(circle);
    circleFeature.style = circlreFeatureStyle;
    VectorLayer.addFeatures(circleFeature);
}

function LineDrawing(Map,VectorLayer)
{
    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);

    var style = {
        strokeColor: 'yellow',
        strokeOpacity: 4.5,
        strokeWidth: 5
    };

    var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
    VectorLayer.removeAllFeatures();
    VectorLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to disable clicking on the line or do you just want to ensure that the points are always on top of the line. Also, could you post some code that is relevant to what you are doing?

Comment: Yes I want to ensure that the point are always on top of the line!

Comment: Sorry, that isn't really enough. We need to be able to actually reproduce your issue, to be able to debug it.

Comment: I reallized that the problem is seems like the line style. If I set null rather than stlye var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, null); like this, it works. But if I set some stlye format than I have a same problem. But I should use line style for nice view.

Comment: Yes, because usually features are drawn in the order that they are added to the layer/map.